# is it possible to avoid port forwarding when running docker on VirtualBox on Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, virtualbox

I would like anyone to access my server via [server-ip-address]:80, but before I can do that I need to update port forward setting on VirtualBox's network setting. (Because docker-machine uses VirtualBox as a hypervisor)

Is there a way to bypass this? Because when I follow the docker tutorial here:

[docker tutorial part 2](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#requirementstxt)

Towards to the end, they simply use localhost to connect to docker-machine ip. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to reachout docker without using port forwarding. The reason for that is, docker creates its own network based on docker0 (virtual adaptor) and bridge connection. This approach by docker restricts any application outside this container to communicate with it unless you expose any port (or using other mechanism) application.

This is a security feature by docker because now application can only be accessed by explicitly exposing ports.

Coming back to your original question, trying to expose docker application   outside localhost without port forwarding is not a good idea. Although, docker allows you to create overlay networks for creating network that spans over multiple machines. You might be interested in something like kubernetes to expose and scale your application.

Comment: Okay, I understand. So what is the recommended procedure for port handling when one is trying to deploy and run a docker image (containing a web application) on a single or several remote servers? Should I still manually port-forward every time I deploy via SSH?

Comment: people usually use puppet or ansible for automating vm creation process and initialization process. If you are trying out something on localhost, try to use commands like vboxmanage and automate this port forwarding using --port-forward-4  flag. I haven't played with it but solution to your issue is something very similar.

Comment: after some searching I found that https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-controlvm does offer something in this area like natpf option as explained here, https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/panamax-ui/wiki/How-To%3A-Port-Forwarding-on-VirtualBox